# Anti symmetrical relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Currently learning about symmetrical and anti symmetrical relations. Been working on assignments but I cant seem to bend my head around this one, especially because I can't understand the solution.

What I thought an anti symmetrical relation is: a pair like $(x,y)$ that also exists as $(y,x)$ with $x = y.$

The question is: describe the relation of the following collection.

$$R = \{(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)\}$$

Answer: anti symmetrical.

Why is this anti symmetrical?

Comment: Can you exhibit any pair $(x,y)$ such that both $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ ar $\in R$?

Comment: No none of the pairs can be substituted in a way that (x,y) becomes (y,x) or that x and y are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $R$ is a relation on a set $A$. When we say that $R$ is *symmetric*, we mean that if one of the pairs $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle b,a\rangle$ is in $R$, then so is the other. When we say that $R$ is *antisymmetric*, we mean that if $a\ne b$, and one of the pairs $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle b,a\rangle$ is in $R$, then the other one is **not** in $R$.

This is the case with your relation

$$R=\{\langle 1,2\rangle,\langle 1,3\rangle,\langle 1,4\rangle,\langle 2,3\rangle,\langle 2,4\rangle,\langle 3,4\rangle\}\;:$$

$\langle 1,2\rangle$ is in it, but $\langle 2,1\rangle$ is not; $\langle 2,3\rangle$ is in it, but $\langle 3,2\rangle$ is not; and so on for every possible pair of distinct elements of $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Note that for both symmetry and antisymmetry it’s perfectly fine to have **neither** pair in the relation. The relation

$$\{\langle 1,2\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle,\langle 1,3\rangle,\langle 3,1\rangle\}$$

is symmetric even though it has neither of the pairs $\langle 2,3\rangle$ and $\langle 3,2\rangle$, and the relation

$$\{\langle 1,2\rangle,\langle 3,1\rangle\}$$

is antisymmetric even though it has neither of the pairs $\langle 2,3\rangle$ and $\langle 3,2\rangle$.

Comment: So anti-symmetrical is either a ≠ b with only 1 of the 2 pairs or a = b with poth the pairs?

Comment: @KiptScriddy: If $a=b$ there really is only one pair: it looks the same either way around. Antisymmetry means that if $a\ne b$, the relation can have **at most one** of the two possible ordered pairs, and if $a=b$, it can have or not have the pair $\langle a,a\rangle$.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you for explaining!

Comment: @KiptScriddy: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 4):

An antisymmetric relation $R$ is such that if $(x, y)$ and $(y, x)$ are both in $R$, then this implies that $x = y$.

It your case, the hypothesis is never satisfied, so the conclusion doesn't matter for any elements. That is, it is *vacuously true* that the relation is antisymmetric.

Another way to look at the property of antisymmetry is that a relation $R$ **is** antisymmetric on a set $S$ **UNLESS** there exists $x, y \in S$ such that $(x, y), (y, x) \in R$, but $x\neq y$. Then, and only then, is the relation **not** antisymmetric.

Comment: Another plus +1 ...

Answer (score 1):

For the definition of an antisymmetric relation see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation). It is unclear to me if this is what you thought. In any case, it is easy to check that your example is antisymmetric.

For example, antisymmetric means that $R$ cannot contain both the pair $(1,2)$ and the pair $(2,1)$ without $1$ and $2$ being equal. This is not the case in the example.

Comment: Yes but why is it anti symmetrical? There is no pair in which (a,b) is also seen as (b,a)

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Remember that if it's *not* antisymmetric, then it contains a pair $(x,y)$ and a pair $(y,x)$ with $x\neq y$. The above relation has no such pairs. The antisymmetry property does not require that the converse of any pair is in the relation.