# Anti-symmetric relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

"A relation R on a set $A$ such that $\forall a, b \in A$, if $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(b, a) \in \mathbb{R}$, then $a = b$ is called anti-symmetric."
Example:
Set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $\mathbb{R}$ is a relation on $A$, where:
$\mathbb{R} = \{(2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)\}$.
$\mathbb{R}$ is anti-symmetric. Why?
From what I can understand from the above definition is, the conditions for anti-symmetry are:
1)   $a,b \in A$
2) $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}$
3) $(b,a) \in \mathbb{R}$
4) $a = b$
Taking the ordered pair $(2,1)$, there is no $(1,2)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Since condition no. 3 (or condition no.2) is violated, hence $\mathbb{R}$ is not anti-symmetric.
If the above quoted definition on anti-symmetry is correct, then how is $\mathbb{R}$ qualified as anti-symmetric?

Comment: The definition says that there we can't find two elements $a,b\in A$  with $a\neq b$ such that both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are in $R$.  By inspection, that property holds for the relation you describe.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your questions, you can find a basic tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Given your separation of the components in the definition of antisymmetric relations, you have written  that a relation that  is antisymmetric must satisfy, for all $a, b \in A$, $(a, b) \in R$ and $(b, a) \in R$ and $a=b$. But you've changed the definition from a conditional to a conjunction.  The two are not equivalent.  A relation is antisymmetric means $a, b \in A$, **If**  $(a, b) \in R$ **and** $(b,a) \in R$, **then** we must have $a = b$.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remember that the condition of anti-symmetry is an implication. It states that *if* $(a,b) \in R$ *and* $(b,a) \in R$ *then* $a=b$. But we do not have that $(1,2) \in R$ *and* $(2,1) \in R$.

If we added the pair $(1,2)$ to $R$, then $R$ would fail to be antisymmetric, since we do not have that $1 = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't break down the conditions as you tried.

The condition that must be met for a relation $R$ to be an antixymmetric, is that $\forall a, b \in A,$ **if** $(a, b) \in R$ *and* $(b, a) \in R,$ **then** $a = b$.

One way to put this is that

The relation is **antisymmetric**  *unless* there exists $(a, b) \in R$ and $(b, a) \in R$, but $a\neq b$.

Note that in your example, the fact that $(2, 1) \in R$ but $(1, 2) \not\in R$ tells us the relation is **not symmetric**.  (if a relation is not symmetric, that doesn't necessarily imply it is antisymmetric).

Looking at all the ordered pairs in the relation you've asked about, because there are no $a,b$ such that $(a, b) \in R$ **and** $(b, a) \in R.$ So it is vacuously antisymmetric.

Recall: 
The relation *is* **antisymmetric**  *unless* there exists $(a, b) \in R$ and $(b, a) \in R$, but $a\neq b$.

Comment: See also this post: [Anti symmetrical relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552908/anti-symmetrical-relation?rq=1), and yet another example [Could someone please explain to me how this binary relation is antisymmetric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077799/could-somebody-please-explain-to-me-how-this-binary-relation-is-anti-symmetric?rq=1)

Comment: Ok, please correct me if I'm wrong. This is the more complete definition on Anti-symmetry of a Relation on a set non-empty A:  "A relation R on a set A is called anti-symmetric if (a,b)∈R and (b,a)∈R, then a=b, or if (a,b)∈R and (b,a)∉R, ∀a,b∈A".  [The additional second part of the definition comes, I think,  from the vacuity property of a set]

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what anti-symmetric relation means. There should be **no** pair $(a,b) \in \mathrm R$ such that $(b,a) \in \mathrm R$. Read the statement carefully, it says -- If $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ both belong to the relation, then $a$ **must** be **equal** to $b$.

Conclusion : The given example *is* anti-symmetric.